# Can I play Seiklus in windowed mode?

Tags: seiklus

I recently downloaded *Seiklus* at the recommendation of a GamingSE [blog.](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/01/seiklus/)

I had it on my old laptop, and was enjoying the game; I would like to enjoy it on my new laptop as well. The problem is, I can't remember how I got it to play in windowed mode on the old laptop. So, my question is:

**How do I set *Seiklus* to windowed mode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, but there may be a workaround.** From the comments on [this archived thread made during Seiklus' development](http://www.autofish.net/clysm/art/video_games/seiklus/publicity/GMC_2003.html), changing windowed/fullscreen was not an option and the author never added it as per [the changelog](http://autofish.net/clysm/art/video_games/seiklus/versions.html). **The possible workaround is that the author added in different resolutions which according to [this](http://games.brothersoft.com/seiklus.html) is toggled by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.** I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try hitting <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> while you're in the game.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these answers worked for me.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you. http://compsimgames.about.com/cs/firsttimehere/ht/gamewindowed.htm

Comment: That didn't work either, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If the other answer doesn't work, I know Seiklus was made using Game Maker, and that the default key to toggle between windowed and fullscreen mode is F4.

Comment: Talk about a silly full screen key, just make sure you don't accidentally hit alt at the same time :P